# If $x_n$ converges to $x$ then $p(x_n)$ converges to $p(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

So, I am going through Understanding Analysis, and this is an exercise in chapter 2 (If $x_n$ converges to $x$ then the polynomial $p(x)$ has $p(x_n)$ converging to $p(x)$. The theorem would be quite obvious if I could use the fact that polynomials are continuous, but I can't figure out how to do it without machinery from continuity.

Comment: Have you proved that addition and multiplication are sequentially continuous?

Comment: The notion of sequential continuity hasn't been introduced.

Comment: You only need two basic facts: if $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$ then $a_n+b_n \to a+b$ and $a_nb_n \to ab$

Comment: Yeah I realized that would make sense

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Let $p(x)=a_dx^d+\dots+a_1 x+ a_0$ then
$$|p(x)-p(y)|\leq |a_d||x^d-y^d|+\dots +|a_1||x-y|.$$
Let $R\geq 1$. If $|x|\leq R$ and $|y|\leq R$, then for $1\leq k\leq d$,
\begin{align*}|x^k-y^k|&=|(x^{k-1} + x^{k-2} y + \ldots + y^{k-1})(x-y)|\\
&\leq (\underbrace{R^{k-1}+\dots+R^{k-1}}_{\text{$k$ times}})|x-y|\leq dR^{d-1}|x-y|.
\end{align*}
Hence if $|x|\leq R$ and $|y|\leq R$ then
$$|p(x)-p(y)|\leq MR^{d-1}|x-y|$$
where $M:=d(|a_d|+\dots +|a_1|)$.

Comment: Something's wrong. $|x^k - y^k| = |(x^{k-1} + x^{k-2} y + \ldots + y^{k-1})(x-y)|$, not $|(x^{k-1} + x^{k-2} + \ldots + 1)(x-y)|$. Also, how does $|x-y| \leqslant R$ imply $|x^{k-1} + \ldots + 1| \leqslant R^{k-1} + \ldots + 1$ ?

Comment: @Adayah Thanks. I edited my answer. BTW, no answering before the first morning coffee!